# Get current embedded pdf page number on a button click event

Tags: javascript, html, embed

I have a embed tag in my html which loads the pdf as below :

```
<embed src="C:\prayas\sample.pdf" type="application/pdf" width="500px" height="600px" />
```

I want to get the current page as soon as i click on the button. This button triggers a function call which will extract the current page number from the pdf.

```
<button id = "page" onclick="getPageNo()" value="button">Find Page</button>
```

Comment: checkout pdfjs. You cant integrate activities inside embed object out of the box

Comment: You can refer this sample https://jsfiddle.net/pdfjs/wagvs9Lf/